# the method I am calling from the comboBox will not run all the code, it only runs part of it

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am making a unit converter and when I call up the methods that are responsible for doing the conversions and setting the answer to a label and catching some errors. When I call the methods lengthConversion and timeConversion it prompts the first error check incorrectly and will not display the answer. I know the if statements for it does work I used them 
    package V4Converter;

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class v4Converter extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    static final double[] TO_CENTM = {1,30.48,2.54,100000,160935,0.1,100,91.44};
    static final double[] TO_FEET = {0.032808399,1,0.083333333334,3280.839895,5280.019685,0.0032808399,3.280839895,3};
    static final double[] TO_INCHE ={0.3937007874,12,1,39370.07874,63360.23622, 0.0393700787,39.37007874,36} ;
    static final double[] TO_KILOM = {0.00001,0.0003048,0.0000254,1,1.60935,0.000001,0.001,0.0009144 } ;
    static final double[] TO_MILE = {0.0000062137,0.0001893932,0.0000157828,0.6213688756,1,6.213688756E-7,0.0006213689,0.0005681797};
    static final double[] TO_MILIM = {10,304.8,25.4,1000000,1609350,1,1000,914.4};
    static final double[] TO_METER = {0.01,0.3048,0.0254,0.001,1609.35,0.001,1,0.9144}; 
    static final double[] TO_YARD = {0.010936133,0.3333333333,0.0277777778,1093.6132983,1760.0065617,1760.0065617,1};


    static final double[] TO_DAY = {1,0.0416666667,1.157407407E-8, 0.0006944444,30.4375,0.0000115741,7,365.25};
    static final double[] TO_HOUR = {24,1,2.777777777E-7,0.0166666667,730.5,0.0002777778,168,8766};
    static final long[] TO_MILLIS = {86400000L,3600000L,1,60000L,2629800000L,1000L,604800000L,31557600000L};
    static final double[] TO_MINUTE = {1440,60,0.0000166667,1,43830,0.0166666667,10080,525960};
    static final double[] TO_MONTH = {0.0328542094,0.0013689254,3.802570537E-10,0.0000228154,1,0.2299794661,12};
    static final double[] TO_SECONDS = {86400,3600,0.001,60,2629800,1,604800,31557600};
    static final double[] TO_WEEK = {0.1428571429,0.005952381,1.653439153E-9,0.0000992063,4.3482142857, 0.0000016534,1,52.178571429};
    static final double[] TO_YEAR = {0.0027378508,0.0001140771,3.168808781E-11,0.0000019013,0.0833333333,3.168808781E-8,0.0191649555,1};


    static final String[] LENGTH_UNIT = {"Centimeters", "Feet", "Inches", "Kilometers", "Miles", "Millimeters", "Meters", "Yards"};
    static final String[] TIME_UNIT = {"Days", "Hours", "Milliseconds", "Minutes", "Month", "Seconds", "Week", "Year"};

    public static final DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat( "#.##" );
    public static final DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat( "#.0000000" );

public v4Converter() {
    initComponents();
    setIcon();  
    setSize(350,250);  
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);     
    comboBoxFrom.setSelectedIndex(0);    
    comboBoxTo.setSelectedIndex(0);
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void initComponents() {

    pnlAnswer = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    lblAnswer = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    btnConvert = new javax.swing.JButton();
    comboBoxFrom = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    comboBoxTo = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    txtField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    btnReset = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnExit = new javax.swing.JButton();
    lblConvertTo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblConvertFrom = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    pnlAnswer.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0), 2));

    lblAnswer.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    lblAnswer.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout pnlAnswerLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(pnlAnswer);
    pnlAnswer.setLayout(pnlAnswerLayout);
    pnlAnswerLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        pnlAnswerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(pnlAnswerLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(lblAnswer, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 154, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    pnlAnswerLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        pnlAnswerLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, pnlAnswerLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(lblAnswer, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );

    btnConvert.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 0, 0));
    btnConvert.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    btnConvert.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 0));
    btnConvert.setText("Convert");
    btnConvert.setActionCommand("Convert To");
    btnConvert.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnConvertActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    comboBoxFrom.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Choose One..", "Length Units", "Time Units" }));
    comboBoxFrom.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            comboBoxFromActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    comboBoxTo.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Choose One..", " " }));
    comboBoxTo.setToolTipText("");
    comboBoxTo.setEnabled(false);
    comboBoxTo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            comboBoxToActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    txtField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 13)); // NOI18N
    txtField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            txtField1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnReset.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 0));
    btnReset.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    btnReset.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 0, 0));
    btnReset.setText("Reset");
    btnReset.setActionCommand("Convert To");
    btnReset.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnResetActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnExit.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 204));
    btnExit.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    btnExit.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 0, 0));
    btnExit.setText("Exit");
    btnExit.setActionCommand("Convert To");
    btnExit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnExitActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    lblConvertTo.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Copperplate Gothic Light", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    lblConvertTo.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 153, 0));
    lblConvertTo.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblConvertTo.setText("Convert to");
    lblConvertTo.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);

    lblConvertFrom.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Copperplate Gothic Light", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    lblConvertFrom.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 153, 0));
    lblConvertFrom.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblConvertFrom.setText("     Convert From");
    lblConvertFrom.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(266, 266, 266)
                    .addComponent(btnExit))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(btnConvert)
                                .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                                .addComponent(btnReset)
                                .addGap(196, 196, 196))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(pnlAnswer, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(comboBoxTo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addComponent(lblConvertTo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 295, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(lblConvertFrom, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(txtField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 157, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(comboBoxFrom, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(lblConvertFrom)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(comboBoxFrom, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(txtField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(btnConvert)
                .addComponent(btnReset)
                .addComponent(btnExit))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(pnlAnswer, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(lblConvertTo))
                .addComponent(comboBoxTo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(98, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnConvertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    String userInput = txtField1.getText(); //userInput equals to whatever the user typed in txtField1

}                                          

private void comboBoxFromActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    String lengthUnits[] = {"Centimeters", "Feet", "Inches", "Kilometers", "Light Years", "Miles", "Meters", "Yards" };  //makes an array called lengthUnits then populates it
    String timeUnits[] = {"Hours", "Milliseconds", "Minutes", "Seconds"};
    if(comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals("Length Units")){
        comboBoxTo.setEnabled(true);  //set the comboBoxTo to be activated
        comboBoxFrom.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel( lengthUnits ) );
        comboBoxTo.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel( lengthUnits ) );
        lengthConversion(); 


    }
    else if(comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals("Time Units")){
        comboBoxTo.setEnabled(true);   //set the comboBoxTo to be activated
        //DefaultComboBoxModel time = new DefaultComboBoxModel(timeUnits);  //makes a new model and fills it from the array timeUnits and will link the 2 comboBox's
        comboBoxFrom.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel( timeUnits ) );  //also makes a new model and fills it from the array timeUnits
        comboBoxTo.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel( timeUnits ) );   //but doesn't link the oomboBox's
            if(comboBoxFrom.getModel().getSelectedItem().equals("Length Untis")){
               lengthConversion(); 
            }
    }

}                                            

private void comboBoxToActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

}                                          

private void txtField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                         


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(v4Converter.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(v4Converter.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(v4Converter.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(v4Converter.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new v4Converter().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

private static javax.swing.JButton btnConvert;
private static javax.swing.JButton btnExit;
private static javax.swing.JButton btnReset;
private static javax.swing.JComboBox<String> comboBoxFrom;
private static javax.swing.JComboBox<String> comboBoxTo;
private static javax.swing.JLabel lblAnswer;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblConvertFrom;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblConvertTo;
private javax.swing.JPanel pnlAnswer;
static javax.swing.JTextField txtField1;

private static void lengthConversion(){

    String userInput = txtField1.getText(); //userInput equals to whatever the user typed in txtField1

    try{
        Double.parseDouble(userInput); //checks to see if the userInput from the txtField1 is an integer if not the catch takes control
        if(comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals(comboBoxTo.getSelectedItem())){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot convert to the same unit type.", "Um, You Forgot Something!!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                return;
        }

        for(String s: LENGTH_UNIT){


            if((comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals(s)) && comboBoxTo.getSelectedItem().equals("Centimeters")){
                double answer = (Double.parseDouble(userInput) * TO_CENTM[comboBoxFrom.getSelectedIndex()]) ;   //converts userInput into a type double then makes the unit conversion
                if((answer %2) == 0 ){
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df1.format(answer)));
                }
                else{
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df2.format(answer)));   
                }
            }
            else if((comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals(s)) && comboBoxTo.getSelectedItem().equals("Feet")){
                double answer = (Double.parseDouble(userInput) * TO_FEET[comboBoxFrom.getSelectedIndex()]) ;   //converts userInput into a type double then makes the unit conversion
                if((answer %2) == 0 ){
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df1.format(answer)));
                }
                else{
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df2.format(answer)));   
                } 
            }
            else if((comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals(s)) && comboBoxTo.getSelectedItem().equals("Inches")){
                double answer = (Double.parseDouble(userInput) * TO_INCHE[comboBoxFrom.getSelectedIndex()]) ;   //converts userInput into a type double then makes the unit conversion
                if((answer %2) == 0 ){
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df1.format(answer)));
                }
                else{
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df2.format(answer)));   
                } 
            }
            else if((comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals(s)) && comboBoxTo.getSelectedItem().equals("Kilometers")){
                double answer = (Double.parseDouble(userInput) * TO_KILOM[comboBoxFrom.getSelectedIndex()]) ;   //converts userInput into a type double then makes the unit conversion
                if((answer %2) == 0 ){
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df1.format(answer)));
                }
                else{
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df2.format(answer)));   
                } 
            }
            else if((comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals(s)) && comboBoxTo.getSelectedItem().equals("Miles")){
                double answer = (Double.parseDouble(userInput) * TO_MILE[comboBoxFrom.getSelectedIndex()]) ;   //converts userInput into a type double then makes the unit conversion
                if((answer %2) == 0 ){
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df1.format(answer)));
                }
                else{
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df2.format(answer)));   
                }
            }
            else if((comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals(s)) && comboBoxTo.getSelectedItem().equals("Millimeters")){
                double answer = (Double.parseDouble(userInput) * TO_MILIM[comboBoxFrom.getSelectedIndex()]) ;   //converts userInput into a type double then makes the unit conversion
                if((answer %2) == 0 ){
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df1.format(answer)));
                }
                else{
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df2.format(answer)));   
                } 
            }
            else if((comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals(s)) && comboBoxTo.getSelectedItem().equals("Meters")){
                double answer = (Double.parseDouble(userInput) * TO_METER[comboBoxFrom.getSelectedIndex()]) ;   //converts userInput into a type double then makes the unit conversion
                if((answer %2) == 0 ){
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df1.format(answer)));
                }
                else{
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df2.format(answer)));   
                }
            }
            else if((comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals(s)) && comboBoxTo.getSelectedItem().equals("Yards")){
                double answer = (Double.parseDouble(userInput) * TO_YARD[comboBoxFrom.getSelectedIndex()]) ;   //converts userInput into a type double then makes the unit conversion
                if((answer %2) == 0 ){
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df1.format(answer)));
                }
                else{
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df2.format(answer)));   
                } 
            }
        }                    
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must type a Number", "HEY IDIOT!!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
    }
 return;   
}

private static void timeConversion(){

    String userInput = txtField1.getText(); //userInput equals to whatever the user typed in txtField1


    try{
        Double.parseDouble(userInput); //checks to see if the userInput from the txtField1 is an integer if not the catch takes control

        if(comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals(comboBoxTo.getSelectedItem())){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot convert to the same unit type.", "Um, You Forgot Something!!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                return;
        }

        for(String s: TIME_UNIT){

            if((comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals(s)) && comboBoxTo.getSelectedItem().equals("Days")){
                double answer = (Double.parseDouble(userInput) * TO_DAY[comboBoxFrom.getSelectedIndex()]) ;   //converts userInput into a type double then makes the unit conversion
                if((answer %2) == 0 ){
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df1.format(answer)));  //if answer is even
                }
                else{
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df2.format(answer)));   //if answer is odd
                }
            }
            else if((comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals(s)) && comboBoxTo.getSelectedItem().equals("Hours")){
                double answer = (Double.parseDouble(userInput) * TO_HOUR[comboBoxFrom.getSelectedIndex()]) ;   //converts userInput into a type double then makes the unit conversion
                if((answer %2) == 0 ){
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df1.format(answer)));
                }
                else{
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df2.format(answer)));   
                } 
            }
            else if((comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals(s)) && comboBoxTo.getSelectedItem().equals("Milliseconds")){
                double answer = (Double.parseDouble(userInput) * TO_MILLIS[comboBoxFrom.getSelectedIndex()]) ;   //converts userInput into a type double then makes the unit conversion
                if((answer %2) == 0 ){
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df1.format(answer)));
                }
                else{
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df2.format(answer)));   
                } 
            }
            else if((comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals(s)) && comboBoxTo.getSelectedItem().equals("Minutes")){
                double answer = (Double.parseDouble(userInput) * TO_MINUTE[comboBoxFrom.getSelectedIndex()]) ;   //converts userInput into a type double then makes the unit conversion
                if((answer %2) == 0 ){
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df1.format(answer)));
                }
                else{
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df2.format(answer)));   
                } 
            }
            else if((comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals(s)) && comboBoxTo.getSelectedItem().equals("Month")){
                double answer = (Double.parseDouble(userInput) * TO_MONTH[comboBoxFrom.getSelectedIndex()]) ;   //converts userInput into a type double then makes the unit conversion
                if((answer %2) == 0 ){
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df1.format(answer)));
                }
                else{
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df2.format(answer)));   
                }
            }
            else if((comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals(s)) && comboBoxTo.getSelectedItem().equals("Seconds")){
                double answer = (Double.parseDouble(userInput) * TO_SECONDS[comboBoxFrom.getSelectedIndex()]) ;   //converts userInput into a type double then makes the unit conversion
                if((answer %2) == 0 ){
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df1.format(answer)));
                }
                else{
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df2.format(answer)));   
                } 
            }
            else if((comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals(s)) && comboBoxTo.getSelectedItem().equals("Week")){
                double answer = (Double.parseDouble(userInput) * TO_WEEK[comboBoxFrom.getSelectedIndex()]) ;   //converts userInput into a type double then makes the unit conversion
                if((answer %2) == 0 ){
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df1.format(answer)));
                }
                else{
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df2.format(answer)));   
                }
            }
            else if((comboBoxFrom.getSelectedItem().equals(s)) && comboBoxTo.getSelectedItem().equals("Years")){
                double answer = (Double.parseDouble(userInput) * TO_YEAR[comboBoxFrom.getSelectedIndex()]) ;   //converts userInput into a type double then makes the unit conversion
                if((answer %2) == 0 ){
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df1.format(answer)));
                }
                else{
                    lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(df2.format(answer)));   
                } 
            }
        }                    
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must type a Number", "HEY IDIOT!!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
    }
return;
}
```

}

Comment: there is too much code... isolate exactly at what part in your code are you experiencing the issue and show that. no one is going to sit here and read through all your code, its too much

Comment: Only thing I could really get rid of is the exit and reset buttons and the labels for from and to.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I'm not completely sure what's going on here, but my first step would be to write one or several unit tests to eliminate the user interface from the equation.  What you show here is a model, and it can be nicely encapsulated in JUnit.  That way you can solve one problem at a time.  Once you know the above code is doing what you want, you can concentrate on the UI.